# Creating Multiple Instances of a Class

Tags: python, class, instance

I am trying to practice my skills in python and came across an old spec from a class a couple years ago. I don't seem to understand this part:

> Outside of the class write a function that takes two parameters. The first is an instance of class. The second is another instance of the class.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where your confused. Could you be more specific? From the spec, it sounds as if said function will take _two, separate instances_ of the same class. An example of the problem would help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: `outside_func(TheClass(), TheClass())` ← A function taking two arguments, both instances of the same class…

Answer (score 2):

The spec is pretty clear. You need to create a function that takes two parameters. Those parameters need to be two separate instances. To use this function you would:

- create an instance of the class and store it in a variable
- create another instance of the class and store it in a second variable
- call the function and pass the first variable as the first parameter and the second variable as the second parameter

In code it would be something like

```
# create instances of class
instance1 = YourClass()
instance2 = YourClass()

# call function, passing instances as arguments (parameters)
your_function(instance1, instance2)
```

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but you don't really _have_ to create two variables to hold the class instances. You can simply do what @deceze said in the comments.

Comment: @ChristianDean I'm being verbose on purpose to clearly illustrate instantiation as one step and passing as another.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers!